# Laravel 5.8 403 This action is unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization, laravel-formrequest

I have `update` method like this

```
  public function update(Contact  $contact)
{

    $this->authorize('ownItems', $contact);
    ......
}
```

and `ContactPolicy` :

```
public function ownItem(User $user,Contact $contact)
{
  return true;
}
```

It work correctly but when I replace `Contcact` to `ContactRequest`  in my `update` method
show me this :

> 403 This action is unauthorized.

`update` method :

```
public function update(ContactRequest  $contact)
{
    $this->authorize('ownItems', $contact);
    .......
}
```

`authorize` method in ContactRequest:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ContactRequest is laravel Request  class not Contact class u need to inject both

Comment: I know this but my problem is `authorize` method. Why it show me `403`

Comment: you have a ownItem meyhod in policy but you call ownItems in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContactRequest` is a laravel `Request` class instance

```php
public function update(ContactRequest $request,Contact  $contact)
{
    $this->authorize('ownItems', $contact);
    .......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled method name in `$this->authorize('ownItems', $contact);`, it should be "ownItem"

## UPD

`ContactRequest` is probably instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` but `authorize` method waiting for `Model` instance, if you do not have model identifier in yout request. first you should to find model: `$model = Contact::find($contact->input('id'))` and than check your policy with `$this->authorize('ownItems', $model)`

Comment: Thanks but it's type mistake.